How do you identify this CSS in jquery
I am having an issue with trying to figure out how to call the & path in the css below
.marker {
      position: relative;
      margin: 0 40px;
      color: #333;
      text-decoration: none;
      //line-height: 1em;
      & svg {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: -50%;
        right: 0; 
        margin-left: auto; 
        margin-right: auto; 
        pointer-events: none;   
      }
      & path {
          transition: stroke-dashoffset 300ms linear;
        stroke-width: 1.0;
        stroke: darkgreen;
        fill: none;
        stroke-linecap: round;
      }
      &:hover path{
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      } 
}

I am trying to mimic mouseover on & path. I don't know how to identify the & path in .marker in javascript, specifically mimicing the hover css. I was using something like this below:
$(".marker").hover(
// Mouse Over


function(e) {
    console.log(e.type);
    $(this).addClass("hover");
},
// Mouse Out


function(e) {
    console.log(e.type);
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
});

var t = 1;
setInterval(function() {
    if (t) {
        $(".marker").mouseenter()
    } else {
        $('.marker').mouseleave();
    }
    t = t?0:1;
}, 1000);

Any help will be much appreciated! Thank you!

By “call the & path” do you mean select?

"I am trying to mimic mouseover on & path." - the effective selector in the CSS is .marker:hover path, meaning this rule applies during hovering of .marker, not of any contained path on its own. So you'll want to keep assigning your handler function via $(".marker").hover(), and then inside that function select the path elements that are descendants of the currently mouseover'd .marker element - $(this).find("path"). And then do whatever you need to, with/to those elements ...

& is SASS shorthand, not standard CSS. & path just means that everything in that nested block is for the selector .marker path.

@C3roe so I tried this:
$(".marker").hover(
// Mouse Over
function(e) {
console.log(e.type);
$(this).find("path").addClass("hover");
},
// Mouse Out
function(e) {
console.log(e.type);
$(this).find("path").removeClass("hover");
});
var t = 1;
setInterval(function() {
if (t) {
$(".marker").mouseenter()
} else {
$('.marker').mouseleave();
}
t = t?0:1;
}, 2000);
I also tried adding the .fin("path") to the $(".marker").mouse functions but it didn't work either

Can you please put that into the question, properly formatted - hard to read in comments.

.find("path").addClass("hover") - do you have any rule in your CSS that applies to path elements that have the class hover? At least in the CSS shown so far, there isn't any.

@C3roe the one with stroke-dashoffset: 0;
So when the .marker & path has hover it is setting the dashoffset. I appologize, I tried following the directions on using code in the reply but it isn't formatting correctly for me

"the one with stroke-dashoffset: 0;" - that rule has the selector .marker:hover path. But you don't have any rule that would apply specifically to path elements that themselves had a class of hover set.

@C3roe right I need to mimic that hover. I have mimiced the hover on just .marker and it wasn't working correctly.
Basically I have jquery that when you mouseover a word with the .marker class it craws a circle around it. When I mimic the hover on .marker with what I had in the original post it starts the drawing (like hand drawing a circle) but it stops. I thought maybe because I needed to include the path part of that CSS.

You are setting the class hover on a .marker element, so if you want path elements inside .marker to be affected by that, you'd need a rule in your CSS with the selector .marker.hover path. What you currently have is .marker:hover path.
